# Space between image and text

Tags: html, css

I wanted to find out how to make space between my image and text. Right now the image and text are tight together. Like there is no space between the text and an image. I tried to do margin and padding but they didn't work.
And I want my text not to be under the picture but for it go downwards not under the image.

Thank you for whoever answers.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmhuk3kq/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you forgot to put "." in your selector, second you don't want the texts go under the image, in that case you cannot use pixels because when the screen goes smaller that texts will go under the image instead use percent. You also have to remove the image element inside the "p" element.

Try this code

**HTML**

```
<img src="Images/female_dentist.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img_dentist"  alt='Dentist'></img>

<p class="paragraph1" >
    She is an accomplished dentist with extensive postdoctoral experience and superior knowledge of orthodontics and laser therapy.  Her experience with dentistry  extends for over 25 years, with 15 years of orthodontics leading her to publish over 30 professional publications and hold a patent in orthodontics' laser therapy in _. </p>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
.paragraph1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}

.img_dentist {
    width: 40%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-left: 10px; 
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

See [demo] (http://jsfiddle.net/gmhuk3kq/7/)

Comment: and also he wants to image is in <p> tag

Comment: Thank you! I put everything like you wrote and everything is working.! Thank you very much again!

Comment: Can you accept this answer as correct by checking my answer, so others will know this is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

please add selector (.) in your div class

```
.paragraph1 {
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.img_dentist {
   width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-left: 40px; 
}
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/c12L6vdy/2/

Comment: He want to make space between image and text not just margin left

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll use totally use your advice. Thanks for the help!